# How do I stop .focusout() from firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's a simple recreation of what Im trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9k4g2vw/1/

```
$('body').on('focusout', 'input', function(){
    alert('test');
});

<input type="text" name="textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="textbox2" />
```

When you focus out of the `<input>`, it runs fine, however, if you focus out of an `<input>` directly into another `<input>`, it creates a loop. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think it's because the the browser is sending focus from the alert to your text field every time you click the alert's "OK" button. You're probably not going to be popping up an alert (methinks) in the final version of your code, so this might not be an issue in the long run.

Comment: @JegadeshBS I think you are right, I just tested it with console and it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: can you accept my code as the right answer or give an up vote?

Comment: I got you, fam..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps... I used JQuery....

```js
$("<input />", {
  type: "number",
  min: "0"
}).addClass("someclass").appendTo($("#someid"));

$(document).on("focusout", ".someclass", function() {
  console.log("alert");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="someclass" />
<div id='someid'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`alert` messes with focus. Your code is fine if you don't use `alert` (or the other old deprecated functions `confirm`, `prompt`, etc.; e.g., the 1990's style bring-the-world-to-a-stop functions):

```js
$('body').on('focusout', 'input', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="textbox2" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right, it works just fine! I've always tested with alert, never knew it was messed up. Thanks!